# What brand of non-Lego bricks are these with hollow studs and diagonal walls on their undersides?

Tags: part-identification, clone-brands, vintage

Believe they are from the 1960’s, available in Australia.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I find the article [Bricks on Display: a collection of interlocking building bricks](https://brickset.com/article/92076/bricks-on-display-a-collection-of-interlocking-building-bricks) on [brickset](https://brickset.com/) to be a good source of information for this kind of question.

These appear to be [Montini](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montini_(toy)) bricks (made by Berco Lux in Tiel, Holland, in the 1960s, as a clone of the early Lego Mursten) :

[image]

[image]

(images are from that same article)

The name of the brand should be engraved on the surface somewhere (between the studs afaict) - can you find it ?

Answer (score 0):

1st guess Montini, made in The Netherlands, but mine had name atop.
Do 2×x have pegs to fit hollow studs? Made of softer plastic than Lego is.